# Changing the Ticks and Slider Control to display Smaller numbers

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I'm trying to ask the user to drag the slider to whatever their weight is. I'm having trouble getting the number of the ticks correct. Currently, I have it so the ticks are 10, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500. I want the tickets to increase by one. They will start at 10 and go all the way to 500.

For example, when I drag the slider, the number will increase (11,12,13). Currently, it is (10, 100, 200).

WPF:

```
<Slider x:Name="sldWeight" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"            
            IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Minimum="10" Maximum="500" TickPlacement="BottomRight"
            AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight" 
            Ticks="10, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500" ValueChanged="sldWeight_ValueChanged"  FontSize="18" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Black" 
            TickFrequency="0" Margin="240,238,328.333,141.667" RenderTransformOrigin="0.32,2.104" Height="41" />
<TextBox x:Name="txtWeightOutput" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="488,227,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94"/>
```

C#

```
 private void sldWeight_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
 {
     if (txtWeightOutput != null)
     {
         txtWeightOutput.Text = sldWeight.Value.ToString();
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove specific tick values and have the tick frequency as 1 (not 0).

```
<Slider x:Name="sldWeight" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"            
                    IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Minimum="10" Maximum="500" TickPlacement="BottomRight"
                    AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight" 
                     ValueChanged="sldWeight_ValueChanged"  FontSize="18" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Black" 
                    TickFrequency="1" Margin="240,238,328.333,141.667" RenderTransformOrigin="0.32,2.104" Height="41" />
```